# Accessing data in mysql database android

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-sqlite

I have successfully added data in my `ArrayClass` from the `Database` below

```
public class DBHelper {

    private final String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/../databases/";
    private final String DATABASE_NAME = "...sqlite";
    private final static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase database = null;
    OpenHelper openHelper=null;
    StringBuilder query =null;
    Cursor cursor=null;

    ArticlesTable articlesTable=new ArticlesTable();
    DestinateurTable destinataireTable = new DestinateurTable();

    public static DBHelper dbHelper = null;

    private DBHelper(Context context) {

    this.context = context;
    openHelper = new OpenHelper(this.context);
    this.database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    try {

        createDataBase();
        openDataBase();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
    public static DBHelper getInstance(Context context)
    {
    if(dbHelper == null)
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
    return dbHelper;
    }

   public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

    //Open the database
    String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
    database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException
    {
    openHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    if(getDBAlreadyCopiedToDeviceOnceFlag(context) == false){
        try {
        copyDataBase();
        setDBAlreadyCopiedToDeviceOnceFlag(context);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }

    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private boolean checkDataBase(){

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try{
        String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

    }catch(SQLiteException e){

        //database does't exist yet.

    }

    if(checkDB != null){

        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

    }

    private class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        SQLiteStatement insertStmt;

        public OpenHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }


    public void setDBAlreadyCopiedToDeviceOnceFlag(Context ctx)
    {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("isDBAlreadyCopiedToDeviceOnce", true);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public boolean getDBAlreadyCopiedToDeviceOnceFlag(Context ctx)
    {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        boolean isDBAlreadyCopiedToDeviceOnce = prefs.getBoolean("isDBAlreadyCopiedToDeviceOnce", false);
        return isDBAlreadyCopiedToDeviceOnce; 
    }

    ////////////////////////////
    //// Write your methods here
    ////////////////////////////

    public ArrayList<Article> getArticlesList(){
        ArrayList<Article> items=new ArrayList<Article>();

        try
        {
            query = new StringBuilder();
            query.append("select * from "+articlesTable.TABLE_NAME);

            cursor=this.database.rawQuery(query.toString(),null);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                do
                {
                    Article a=new Article();

                    a.enseigne=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(articlesTable.ENSEIGNE));
                    a.tel=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(articlesTable.TEL));
                    a.fax=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(articlesTable.FAX));
                    a.latitude=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(articlesTable.LATITUDE));
                    a.longitude=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(articlesTable.LONGITUDE));

                    a.adresse1=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(articlesTable.ADRESSE1));
                    a.adresse2=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(articlesTable.ADRESSE2));
                    a.adresse3=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(articlesTable.ADRESSE3));
                    a.adresse4=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(articlesTable.ADRESSE4));
                    a.adresse5=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(articlesTable.ADRESSE5));
                    a.adresse6=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(articlesTable.ADRESSE6));

                    a.horaires1=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(articlesTable.HORAIRE1));
                    a.horaires2=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(articlesTable.HORAIRE2));
                    a.horaires3=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(articlesTable.HORAIRE3));
                    a.horaires4=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(articlesTable.HORAIRE4));
                    a.horaires5=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(articlesTable.HORAIRE5));
                    a.horaires6=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(articlesTable.HORAIRE6));
                    a.horaires7=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(articlesTable.HORAIRE7));

                    items.add(a);

                    System.out.println("added_items:"+items);
                }
                while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed())
            {
            cursor.close();

            }
        }
        catch(SQLiteException e){

            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        return items;
    }
    //--here
    public boolean addArticle(Article a){
        this.database.beginTransaction();

        try{

            ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();

            contentValues.put(articlesTable.ENSEIGNE, a.enseigne);
            contentValues.put(articlesTable.TEL, a.tel);
            contentValues.put(articlesTable.FAX, a.fax);

            contentValues.put(articlesTable.LATITUDE, a.latitude);
            contentValues.put(articlesTable.LONGITUDE, a.longitude);
            contentValues.put(articlesTable.ADRESSE1, a.adresse1);
            contentValues.put(articlesTable.ADRESSE2, a.adresse2);
            contentValues.put(articlesTable.ADRESSE3, a.adresse3);
            contentValues.put(articlesTable.ADRESSE4, a.adresse4);
            contentValues.put(articlesTable.ADRESSE5, a.adresse5);
            contentValues.put(articlesTable.ADRESSE6, a.adresse6);

            contentValues.put(articlesTable.HORAIRE1, a.horaires1);
            contentValues.put(articlesTable.HORAIRE2, a.horaires2);
            contentValues.put(articlesTable.HORAIRE3, a.horaires3);
            contentValues.put(articlesTable.HORAIRE4, a.horaires4);
            contentValues.put(articlesTable.HORAIRE5, a.horaires5);
            contentValues.put(articlesTable.HORAIRE6, a.horaires6);
            contentValues.put(articlesTable.HORAIRE7, a.horaires7);

            this.database.insert(articlesTable.TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
        this.database.setTransactionSuccessful();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }finally{
            this.database.endTransaction();
        }
        return true;
    }


    public boolean deleteArticle(String id){
        try
        {
            String query="delete from " + articlesTable.TABLE_NAME+" where "+articlesTable.NOM+"='"+id+"'";
            this.database.execSQL(query);
        }
        catch(SQLiteException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

In the code above, `Article a=new Article();` is a class holding values as below:

```
public class Article {
    public String enseigne, type,nom,latitude,longitude,
    tel,fax,adresse1,adresse2,adresse3,adresse4,adresse5,
    adresse6,horaires1,horaires2,horaires3,horaires4,horaires5,
    horaires6,horaires7 ;
}
```

In my `MainActivity.class` in `onCreate()` method. I want to print name. How can i achieve this.
In `MainActivity.class` i initialize a `Article` like follows `Article a = new Article();` then call `a.name` but this isn't the way.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new instance by using `Article a = new Article()`, so all the `String` variable are `null` for the new object.

In the `MainActivity` call the `DbHelper` class method `getArticlesList()` and get the `ArrayList` that the method `returns`. Then you can use `nameOfArrayList.get(position).name` and others...

Hope this helps...

Comment: DBHelper helper = DBHelper.getInstance(context);
        ArrayList<Article> mArticles = helper.getArticlesList();

  
  System.out.println("TODAY: "+ mArticles.get(0).adresse1); not working

Comment: "Not working" means?  And is there data in the database? i.e. have you added the data in datatbase?

Comment: yes the database has data. "Not working"represents actual output="TODAY: " only. expected output "TODAY: addresse1"

Comment: does this `System.out.println("added_items:"+items);` print statement in the method `getArticlesList()` is printed?  And can you just uninstall your app and again install it and then check.

Comment: don't worry i am implementing setter and getter method it is working with it

Answer (score 0):

1) In your onCreate() you're going to want to instiantiate your DBHelper class

```
DBHelper dbhelper = new DBHelper();
```

2) In onCreate() you'll call getArticlesList()

```
ArrayList<Article> mArticles = dbhelper.getArticlesList();
```

3) When you want to use an article, just grab whichever one you want by index:

```
Article = mArticles.get(x);
```

That should be exactly what you need.

Comment: i did this but nothing get displayed 
        DBHelper helper = DBHelper.getInstance(context);
        ArrayList<Article> mArticles = helper.getArticlesList();

  
  System.out.println("TODAY: "+ mArticles.get(0).adresse1);

Comment: Did you really use System.out.println()?  That call displays to console for regular Java, but to see output in LogCat, where I"m guessing you're looking, you're going to have to use Log messages.  Something like android.util.Log.i("myTag", "mArticles adresse1 = " + mArticles.get(0).adresse1);  Then you can search through LogCat for "myTag" and see your message.

Comment: Just to clarify, you have an existing database with all article information and you have verified that the original database is populated correctly.  You try to copy it and then you try to use the copy in your activity?  Also, your onCreate() in OpenHelper is empty, without even a call to super.onCreate() -- this is where you normally create the database if it doesn't exist, or in your case, you copy it.  Normally, DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper directly, but you have it in a private inner class.  I'm not suggesting you throw away your code, but simplify it.

Comment: By "simplify" I mean make sure a simple example works before returning to a complex example so that you can establish proof of concept.  Try this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html and implement what he has in section 4.3.  Make yourself a little database with one table and three columns, _id, nom, prenom and try running a rawQuery to select nom from myTable where prenom = 'Christina'; and see if that works.  After that, you can see how things work or don't work and we can move on from there.